# Intelligent String Parsing in java

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split, java.util.scanner

I have an email Subject line that i need to parse. I need to find first occurance of any word given in a list of words and get the next word which can be separated by

```
('=' or ',' or ';' or 'blank' or '.').
```

for example

> list of word for customer ["customer","client","kunden","kd.nr."]
>
> list of word for Order ["order","auftrag","auftragsnummer","auftragnr."]
>
> separator : [= , ; .]

```
subjectline:  Customer 2013ABC has send an Aufrag 2056899A for Motif=A
```

I need to parse the information like

```
customer=2013ABC 
order=2056899A 
Motif=A
```

I am using Java 7 so Scanner class can be used as well.

Thanks for any tips in advance

Comment: Where do these emails come from? Do you generate them yourself? If yes, just use `X-` headers instead of having to parse the subject

Comment: No these emails come from different agents . Email subjects are parsed so we can sort and assign email automatically into the central system.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using regular expressions, here is a sample code:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(customer|client|kunden|kd\\.nr\\.)[=,;\\. ]*(\\w*).*(order|auftrag|auftragsnummer|auftragnr\\.)[=,;\\. ]*(\\w*).*[ ](.*)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    String subject = "subjectline: kd.nr. 2013ABC has send an Auftrag 2056899A for Motif=A";

    Matcher m = p.matcher(subject);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " : " + m.group(2) );
        System.out.println(m.group(3) + " : " + m.group(4));
        System.out.println(m.group(5));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. using the Pattern you mentioned, unfortunately it will not work if the subject line doesn't have the text "Aufrag" etc. Infact subject line will have any text and i have to look for the customer no, order no. etc. All three (customer, order and motif) number can be there in subject line. or only one of them.

Comment: you did not mentioned that in your question

Comment: In that case you need to look for the cutover number and order number pattern in your subject line like ####XXX and #######X

Comment: Ok, I tried the following for customer no only : `code` Pattern customerNoPattern = Pattern.compile(".*\\w(" + regex + ")[=,;\\.! ]*(\\w*).*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`code`. it is not working for `code` String subject = "subjectline: Kundenummer  !, =2013ABC  has send an Auftrag 2056899A for Motif=A"; `code`